# Proper way to add folder to Classpath using Maven3

Tags: jar, websphere, maven-3, websphere-8

So I am using WAS8.5 and I need to include the WAS libs in my project. I tried this...

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
          <manifest>
              <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
          </manifest>
          <manifestEntries>
              <Class-Path>C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\plugins</Class-Path>
              <Class-Path>C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre\lib</Class-Path>
          </manifestEntries>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

but I still see...

> error: package javax.jms does not exist

despite...

> Binary file ./plugins/javax.j2ee.jms.jar matches

But that doesn't seem to work for mvn package so my question is kind of 2 fold

1.) Should I be using mvn package or mvn jar:jar because the later doesn't seem to recognize the storage location of my classes. If I am supposed to use jar how do I include the source directory.

2.) If I am using package how do I include the folder in the classpath?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're talking about compile-time issues instead of runtime issues. The manifest-information is for runtime and the way you configured it right makes it only useful for your system.
Apache Maven is about predictable builds, which means you have to define every dependency instead of defining a library-folder.
You should 'install' the required jars to your local repository (install is actually a copy to).
See http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: So that is what I ended up doing but that is tedious is that really the only solution?

Comment: It is the best solution. All other tricks are hacks and will bite you one day. I assume (or hope) you're not switching to a newer version every day, week or month. It's a one-time install of these jars. You can compare your situation with http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-coping-with-sun-jars.html

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found for automatizing the build and not bothering with command line was to install from my pom.xml with maven-install-plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>                    
                <execution>
                    <id>proguard</id>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <file>${pom.basedir}/lib/proguard-4.8.jar</file>
                        <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                        <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard</artifactId>
                        <version>4.8</version>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                        <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
           </plugin>
```

So I put my jar into a $PROJECT_HOME/lib folder and add this execution to a validate phase so that it's installed on each maven execution.

That's a lot of text, but it completely automatizes the build on other machines.